# Run multiple commands in MacOS Terminal fails

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have those commands, where the **second command** has `&` at the end

```
command-1
command-2 &
command-3
```

I created an alias to run them all in `/.bash_profile` as following:

```
alias aws_dev="command-1 && command-2 && command-3"
```

but I'm getting an error saying the following:

```
error token "&&"
```

any ideas? or I might be doing it the wrong way!

Comment: ```ls ~ && `pwd &` && cd ~/Desktop```, command-1=ls ~, command-2=pwd &, command-3=cd ~/Desktop, command2 is with &

Comment: nop, it didn't work! I got this: `syntax error near unexpected token \`&&`

Comment: ` this is back tick and there is space between ` and && , works fine for me in zsh and bash